# Lazy loading views

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating an AngularJS web app and have a question. While researching it was said that loading all JavaScript view files in index.html file is what is recommended. I have a logic part and dashboard part. It doesn't make sense to me to load the dashboard and dashboard partials JavaScript files when the user is first going to attempt to login. Is there any way to lazy load the dashboard files when needed? Perhaps in the dashboard.html file instead of the index.html?

I have attempted to do so but I get angular errors.

Comment: what error do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think its best practice, you can just have the JS files reference to sit in your dashboard.html and when you inject that html (ngInclude probably?) those JavaScripts will load.

Another thing you can do, if your issue is with the login part, is separate the login procedure from the Index.html file, so only when he actually logs in the loading will take place.